# File Structure of Windows Universal Platforms Apps

Tags: c#, android, windows, uwp

I'm coming from an Android Developing background, was thinking of what the file structure in Window's App really is?

> *The file Structure in Android having Res,Manifests,Activities,and so on is pretty clear to me, I was thinking it will be cool if anyone can explain windows app using those terminologies*

I concluded some thing's things like

> *Windows in android is..*
>
> *xaml is .xml*
>
> *Page is Activity*
>
> *Asset is Res*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome! :-)

In your Windows App you'll have a :

- **XAML Page** `.xaml` which is the design/ UI of your app .. It can be defined along with the .cs file =>
- The XAML Page have a **Code Behind** Which is the `.cs` file if you're using C# .
- Any Image/ ICON/ JSON/ SQL/ File/ Anything actually can save it on your app path in your project and you can't add files to this path while runtime .. But you've the local storage `'ApplicationData'` namespace .. All these things can called **Assets** .

Please take a look at this guide in the Dev Center of Windows : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx

**UPDATE :**

- In every app we have something called **'Package.appxmanifest'**, You can edit anything related to the app and the visuals/ declarations / capabilities and the packaging ..  Name of the app/ languages/ look screen notification / tile update ..
- You always can add a Reference/ Library by clicking on **'References'**   and browse to the path of your reference, it can be online from **'NuGet'** .
- Finally, We have the **Properties** of the project, like build/ debug settings , targeted .NET version .. etc.

That's it all!

Comment: I have used NuGet, but what is it exactly? Is it just a Binder of Libraries?

Comment: It's like a libraries store :D .. you can get a libraries from it like JSON as an example, you can get a library to deserialize the JSON file, Or maps extension .. etc. Package Manager : http://www.nuget.org/

Comment: I sometime before used to get error saying *Nuget was not able to load !* and VS2015 was not able to create the App.What could might have been the issue?

Comment: I think that there was a problem in the Preview SDK and the RC dev tools before the public release :)

Comment: yeah, sure that was there, it was very new. Could be, but not sure.

Comment: We have Activity, Services,Broadcast receiver in Android, what are there equivalent in Windows App?

Comment: Services > BackgroundTask, App Service  .. We don't have Broadcast Receiver !

Comment: The how would you now that call is coming? If you want to perform action just before that broadcast?

Comment: **The XAML Page have a Code Behind Which is the .cs file if you're using C#** Here is it totally impossible to use one view with two different .cs file?